# cloning git hub repository on ubuntu

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, sdk, git-clone

trying to clone the following github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c.git

here is the command the tutorial suggested to use:

git clone -b <lts_07_2022> https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c.git

i have tried the following:

souandji@DESKTOP-M5EE2IM:~$ git clone -b <lts_07_2022_Ref01> https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c.git
-bash: lts_07_2022_Ref01: No such file or directory
souandji@DESKTOP-M5EE2IM:~$ git clone -b <lts_07_2022> https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c.git
-bash: lts_07_2022: No such file or directory
souandji@DESKTOP-M5EE2IM:~$ git clone -b <LTS_07_2022_Ref01> https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c.git
-bash: LTS_07_2022_Ref01: No such file or directory

im unsure what im doing wrong can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try just doing

```
git clone -b lts_07_2022 https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c.git
```

or

```
git clone --branch lts_07_2022 https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c.git
```